# Why is file geodatabase so large when feature classes inside do not add up to anywhere near as much?

Tags: arcmap, file-geodatabase, map-package, arcreader

I recently noticed when publishing maps for use on ArcReader from ArcMap that when I create the map package my file size is now 18GB when it used to be around 800MB. I have not added any new feature classes to my file geodatabase that I am using to create feature classes for the map packages. I have no idea why there is this huge spike in data. When I create a map package it creates a pmf folder where the actual map resides and a data folder where all the geodatabase info is being stored. There are three cw folders, cw00, cw10, cw20, and under cw00 there is a file name a00000075 and it says it is a GDBTABLE File that has 16.6 GB in it but I have no idea how to tell what feature class it is coming from.

Here attached is what the file looks like

[image]

Comment: Can you make that screenshot smaller? it doesn't need to be so large.

Comment: Yes I can do that

Comment: To clarify, The geodatabase that gets created when you make the map package is 18 GB? The source files are in a different format(s) or is source just one geodatabase?

Comment: My file geodatabase itself is 18gb but when i look at the file sizes of the feature classes inside it they don't add up to 18gb but when I make the map package it uses the file geodatabase in which the feature classes in my map reside in. Then when you look at the data in the map package in picture above in the data folder cw00 the one table says its 16.6 gb but i do not know how to figure out which feature class it belongs to because I have no idea how to do that. The source is just from one file geodatabase Matthew and they are all feature classes.

Comment: There is no way to know which feature class the 16.6 gb file belongs to. Do as Vince suggested and copy the feature classes to a new gdb. You could try the Repair Geometry tool on the individual feature classes.

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification.  It's not fair to those who would help to need to scan comments for critical information.

Answer (score 3):

Try to run the Compact command on your geodatabase to see if that will remove some the files that are no longer in use.

(From the ArcGIS online help, version 10.3)

**Compact (Data Management)**

```
Compacts a personal or file geodatabase. Compacting rearranges 
how the geodatabase is stored on disk, often reducing its size
and improving performance.
```

Usage

- It is recommended to compact personal geodatabases when they become
  larger than 250 MB.
- If data entry, deletion, or general editing is frequently performed
  on a database, the database should be regularly compacted to ensure
  optimal performance.
- If a database is open in ArcMap for editing, it cannot be compacted.
  To compact the database, remove any layers with a source table or
  feature class in that database from the Table of Contents.

Comment: My file geodatabase only went from 18.25GB to 18.24GB when I used the Compact command. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried export it to XML workspace document. To do this, right click on the geodatbase and scroll down and it is just before the last one.  More info here http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/importing-a-geodataase-schema-from-an-xml-workspace-document.htm    See if that helps you ?

Comment: what are the advantages of doing this?

Comment: There *aren't* any advantages to exporting to XML, but copying all the feature classes to a newly created FGDB might address your issue (and would be *way* faster, and use ***much*** less space.